# Problem with extending class JLabel to add to it property dragging

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jlabel, jcomponent

I have class JLabelExtended, which extends class javax.swing.JLabel.
I extend it, because I want to add property dragging using mouse.
Here is my code:

```
public class JLabelExtended extends JLabel {
private MouseMotionAdapter mouseMotionAdapter;

private JLabelExtended jLabelExtended;

public LabelEasy(String text) {
    super(text);
    jLabelExtended = this;

    mouseMotionAdapter = new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getX() + "  :   " + e.getY());
            jLabelExtended.setLocation(e.getX(), e.getY()
            );
        }
    };

    jLabelExtended.addMouseMotionListener(mouseMotionAdapter);
}
```

}

This is console part after label dragged:

```
163  :   163
144  :   -87
163  :   162
144  :   -88
163  :   161
144  :   -89
```

I have several questions:

1. Why e.getY() takes negative results?
2. When I drag my label there are appeares copy of label which drags near my label. How can I fix it?
3. When I drag my label, it drags  very slowly.For example: when I move my cursor on 10 points my label moves only on 5 point. How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Here are else one way to extend JLabel:

public class LabelEasy extends JLabel {
    private MouseAdapter moveMouseAdapter;
    private MouseMotionAdapter mouseMotionAdapter;

```
private LabelEasy jLabelExtended;

private int xAdjustment, yAdjustment;
Boolean count = false;

public LabelEasy(String text) {
    super(text);
    jLabelExtended = this;

    moveMouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == 1) {
                xAdjustment = e.getX();
                yAdjustment = e.getY();
            }
        }
    };

    mouseMotionAdapter = new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (count) {
                System.out.println(e.getX() + "  :   " + e.getY());
                jLabelExtended.setLocation(xAdjustment + e.getX(), yAdjustment + e.getY());
                count = false;
            } else {
                count = true;
            }
            ;
        }
    };

    jLabelExtended.addMouseMotionListener(mouseMotionAdapter);
    jLabelExtended.addMouseListener(moveMouseAdapter);
}
```

}

But it works like previous variant.

Comment: Those locations are suspiciously sequenced. X toggles between 163 and 144 while the two interspersed Y sequences decrease by 1 each time. I wonder if you're getting a second event fired due to the label moving? Random ideas to try: create a partially-transparent view of the label that gets moved while the old label stays in place. Or attach the listener to the label's container instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're doing it wrong.  The MouseMotionListener is added to the JLabel and its location is **relative to the JLabel**, not the Container which holds the JLabel, so the information is useless to help you drag it.  You may wish to use a MouseAdapter and add it both as a MouseListener and a MouseMotionListener.  On mousePressed, get the location of the JLabel and the mouse relative to the screen and then use that for your dragging on mouseDragged.  Myself, I wouldn't extend JLabel to do this but would rather just use a regular JLabel, but that's my preference.

Edit: it worked better for me when I dealt with the mouse's position relative to the screen (by calling getLocationOnScreen) and the JLabel's position relative to its Container (by calling getLocation).  For e.g.,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DragLabelEg {
    private static final String[] LABEL_STRINGS = { "Do", "Re", "Me", "Fa",
            "So", "La", "Ti" };
    private static final int HEIGHT = 400;
    private static final int WIDTH = 600;
    private static final Dimension MAIN_PANEL_SIZE = new Dimension(WIDTH,
            HEIGHT);
    private static final int LBL_WIDTH = 60;
    private static final int LBL_HEIGHT = 40;
    private static final Dimension LABEL_SIZE = new Dimension(LBL_WIDTH,
            LBL_HEIGHT);
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private Random random = new Random();

    public DragLabelEg() {
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(MAIN_PANEL_SIZE);
        mainPanel.setLayout(null);

        MyMouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
        for (int i = 0; i < LABEL_STRINGS.length; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(LABEL_STRINGS[i], SwingConstants.CENTER);
            label.setSize(LABEL_SIZE);
            label.setOpaque(true);
            label.setLocation(random.nextInt(WIDTH - LBL_WIDTH),
                    random.nextInt(HEIGHT - LBL_HEIGHT));
            label.setBackground(new Color(150 + random.nextInt(105),
                    150 + random.nextInt(105), 150 + random.nextInt(105)));
            label.addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);
            label.addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapter);

            mainPanel.add(label);
        }
    }

    public JComponent getMainPanel() {
        return mainPanel;
    }

    private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
        private Point initLabelLocation = null;
        private Point initMouseLocationOnScreen = null;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getSource();
            // get label's initial location relative to its container
            initLabelLocation = label.getLocation();

            // get Mouse's initial location relative to the screen 
            initMouseLocationOnScreen = e.getLocationOnScreen();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            initLabelLocation = null;
            initMouseLocationOnScreen = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // if not dragging a JLabel
            if (initLabelLocation == null || initMouseLocationOnScreen == null) {
                return;
            }
            JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getSource();

            // get mouse's new location relative to the screen
            Point mouseLocation = e.getLocationOnScreen();

            // and see how this differs from the initial location.
            int deltaX = mouseLocation.x - initMouseLocationOnScreen.x;
            int deltaY = mouseLocation.y - initMouseLocationOnScreen.y;

            // change label's position by the same difference, the "delta" vector
            int labelX = initLabelLocation.x + deltaX;
            int labelY = initLabelLocation.y + deltaY;

            label.setLocation(labelX, labelY);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createGui();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("App");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new DragLabelEg().getMainPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do, what you say. But it doesn't explain why appears copy of my label near and why coordinates changes so strangely.

Comment: As an example of what I meant, please see the edit and code above.

Comment: Thanks very much. It realy helped me.